# Unable to install SQL Server(setup.exe) Exit code decimal: -2061893606

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

This is what happens when the installation is completed.

I've tried deleting every residual file from previous installations and I've even restarted my laptop and tried installing the express version as well, but I got the same results.

[image]

For those who can't open the image.
"Error description: Wait on Database Engine recovery handle failed.Check the Sql Server error log for potential causes."

Comment: -2061893606 is 0x851A001A. See the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003281/sql-server-installation-fails-with-error-code-0x851a001a-wait-on-the-databas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

Followed next info from link above:

**Registry Editor**

1. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device`.
2. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then select Multi-String value.
   Name it `ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes`.
3. Modify the new value, type in `* 4095`. Click OK and close the Registry editor.

**Command Prompt as Administrator**

1. Add the key. Console

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t   REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
```

2. Validate if the key was added successfully.

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes"
```

**PowerShell as Administrator**

1. Add the key.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" Name   "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" -PropertyType MultiString Force -Value "* 4095"
```

2. Validate if the key was added successfully.

```
Copy Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" -Name   "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes"
```

Comment: [Resolutions: Microsoft is currently investigating this problem.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size#:~:text=Resolutions,investigating%20this%20problem.)  How did that work?

Comment: I used the registry editor and followed the instructions. That's all i did. It was hard getting to it though.

Comment: Thanks! This worked with me. I followed the steps, uninstalled all SQL server components, restarted the computer, started installing SQL server again and it installed without errors.